# Javascript algorithm error 3

Tags: javascript, logic, do-while

I have written down this code, for like a minigame with a password, and I want that if he writes the password right, or writes end, then it really ends, showing us a message, but in case he writes other stuff or nothing that it continues to ask, but It is not completely right.

```js
 do{
                    var password = prompt("What is the password? Just give up by typing end, you won't find it, heheeh.")
                    if(password == "I11I1II1I"){
                        window.alert("Ok, ahha, so fun, going to the code, and searching for the password, yes yes yes good job, you won, yey")    
                    }
                    else if(password == "end"){
                        window.alert("Bye Bye, ehhe.")    
                    }
                    else{
                        window.alert("I don't know how you found me, but hey, you won't find the password, eehhehe.")
                    }
                }
                while((password == "") || (password != "I11I1II1I") || (password != "end"))
```

Comment: How is it "not completely right"? What's your outcome, what do you want to do with this code once is "completely right"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You while logic is wrong, you should the prompt when password is `""` or `(password != "I11I1II1I" && password != "end")`

```js
do{
                password = prompt("What is the password? Just give up by typing end, you won't find it, heheeh.")
                if(password == "I11I1II1I"){
                    window.alert("Ok, ahha, so fun, going to the code, and searching for the password, yes yes yes good job, you won, yey") ;   
                }
                else if(password == "end"){
                    window.alert("Bye Bye, ehhe.")  ;
                }
                else{
                    window.alert("I don't know how you found me, but hey, you won't find the password, eehhehe.");
                }

            }
            while((password == "") || (password != "I11I1II1I" && password != "end"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp):

```
while(true) {

    var password = prompt("What is the password? Just give up by typing end, you won't find it, heheeh.")

    if(password == "" || password == null) {
          // No password, just break or do something else
          break;
    }
    if(password === "I11I1II1I") {
          window.alert("Ok, ahha, so fun, going to the code, and searching for the password, yes yes yes good job, you won, yey");
          break;
    }
    else if(password === "end") {
          window.alert("Bye Bye, ehhe.");    
          break;
    }
    else {
          window.alert("I don't know how you found me, but hey, you won't find the password, eehhehe.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still, one thing is still not fully working, because when i don't type anything, it just ends, which is not suppose.

UPDATE: Oh Forget, i figured it out, I just tooked out the break;on the null section, thanks man for all, that link to w3schools was what made me think about this :).